# CSS - Select a div "outside" some other elements

Tags: html, css, selector

I think I'm looking for something not possible, but let's try:

I need to select all the `div` elements with `class="product-block"` that contain an image with `alt="ing1"`.

This is the code, for reference:

```html
    <div class="product-block">
                          <div class="aos-animate">
                            <div class="image-wrap">
                    <img class="lazyautosizes lazyloaded" alt="ing1">
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Would be a use case for `:has()`, but no browser support apart from Safari yet. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has

Comment: Why don't you add a unique class to the img with that `alt` and on the selector you add `.product-block > .img-class`

Comment: @manjirosano because I need to select the "product-block", not the .img